# How to change F# related colors in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#

I know about Options->Fonts and Colors. But there is no option for F# strings(i want to change color to make them look exactly like c# strings)!

And maybe someone know about Microsoft plans on F# editor (refactoring and etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "String" type in the Fonts and Colors dialog controls the coloring of F# string literals (do you see otherwise?).

There are some other outstanding bugs in Fonts and Colors for F#, even as of Beta2 (see [here](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/12059.aspx)).

There won't be any automatic refactorings for F# in the first release (VS2010).

Comment: Yes, now i see. I was confused by the fact that there just "String" not "F# String" nor "C# String" as i expected.